# NullPointerException is thrown, but the object is created and correctly return values

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, java.util.scanner

Working on a program that has a library of shapes saved in a folder and instruction files (the describe the specifics of the drawing). Ran into a problem when trying to develop the `draw()` method (has a call from the main). main first creates 9 drawings and then draws all of them.
when `draw()` is called a NullPointerException is thrown about the :

```
DrawingPanel dp = new DrawingPanel(canvasI.getWidth(), canvasI.getHeight())
```

why? if you need any more details, please let me know

```java
private ArrayList<Shape> allShapes;
private ArrayList<DrawInstruction> allDrawInstructions;
private CanvasInstruction canvasI;
private DrawInstruction drawI;

public Drawing(ShapeLibrary shapeLib, File oneShape) throws FileNotFoundException{
    try{
        allDrawInstructions = new ArrayList<DrawInstruction>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(oneShape);
        CanvasInstruction canvasI = CanvasInstruction.readFromFile(in);
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            DrawInstruction drawInstruction = DrawInstruction.readFromFile(in);
            allDrawInstructions.add(drawI);
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File doesn't exist");
    }
}


public void draw(){
    DrawingPanel dp = new DrawingPanel(canvasI.getWidth(), 
    canvasI.getHeight());
}
```

Comment: `CanvasInstruction canvasI = CanvasInstruction.readFromFile(in);` will create a new local variable that is only available inside the method it is created. If you want to set the value of your field variable change it to `canvasI = CanvasInstruction.readFromFile(in);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The local variable at line `CanvasInstruction canvasI = CanvasInstruction.readFromFile(in);` inside constructor hides
`private CanvasInstruction canvasI` field. Change code as below:-

```
public Drawing(ShapeLibrary shapeLib, File oneShape) throws FileNotFoundException {
    //...
    Scanner in = new Scanner(oneShape);
    this.canvasI = CanvasInstruction.readFromFile(in);
    //...
}
```

Comment: Awesome. I knew it was something from the basics, but couldn't put my finger on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you declare a variable to hold a CanvasInstruction canvasI object twice. The one you're creating in your try{} block is not being assigned to the variable canvasI that you instantiated around line 3. It's creating one only available in the scope of Drawing. Then when you call canvasI.getHeight() it's referring to the object variable that is on line 3. Which is in fact null at that point.

You're going to want to change

```
CanvasInstruction canvasI = CanvasInstruction.readFromFile(in);
```

to

```
canvasI = CanvasInstruction.readFromFile(in);
```

Answer (score 0):

So you are getting a NullpointerException on canvasI.
This is because you don't initialize the class variable in the constructor but a local variable.

```
public Drawing(ShapeLibrary shapeLib, File oneShape) throws FileNotFoundException{
    try{
        allDrawInstructions = new ArrayList<DrawInstruction>();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(oneShape);
        this.canvasI = CanvasInstruction.readFromFile(in);
        while(in.hasNextLine()){
            DrawInstruction drawInstruction = DrawInstruction.readFromFile(in);
            allDrawInstructions.add(drawI);
        }
    } catch(FileNotFoundException e){
        throw new FileNotFoundException("File doesn't exist");
    }
}
```

This will initialize your class variable.

Comment: It is not class variable. Instead `private CanvasInstruction canvasI` is an instance or object variable.

Comment: It was a poor explanation by me, but it was ment as class scoped variable (or member variable)